# React Hook Form with Typescript - Type 'UseFormRegister<User>' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<HTMLInputElement>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I have a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-2frbvp?file=App.tsx)

I'm trying to create a simple react hook form with typescript

I have the form displaying locally but for some reason it won't display here abd I get `t.split is not a function` this is not my question though.

On the inputs I am using `ref={register}` which is what I have seen in tutorials but on the ref I get the error

`Type 'UseFormRegister<User>' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<HTMLInputElement>'. Type 'UseFormRegister<User>' is not assignable to type '(instance: HTMLInputElement) => void'. Types of parameters 'name' and 'instance' are incompatible. Type 'HTMLInputElement' is not assignable to type '"email" | "password" | "firstname" | "lastname" | "age" | "confirmpassword"'. Type 'HTMLInputElement' is not assignable to type '"confirmpassword"'.(2322) index.d.ts(137, 9): The expected type comes from property 'ref' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>'`

Does anyone know why this is or how to fix this.

Comment: why are you using ref? the new versión of `react-hook-form` says you should do this way: ```<input {...register("example")} />``` 
[link](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started)

Comment: so this seems to work in the demo but in my app locally its errors saying `'name' is specified more than once, so this usage will be overwritten.`

Answer (score 0):

React Refs are of a specific type with a generic type attached (LegacyRef).

The type of `register` is `UseFormRegister<User>` which is not compatible with react refs.

Perhaps the tutorial you referenced used register in a different way or another parameter?